# Creating a app in Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I am very new to all this.

I am trying to install jhipster and have installed all the software required.

What I am doing, what is happening and what is the problem?

1. Created an dir named myapplication
2. accessing the dir using sd myapplication
3. Typed Yo jhipster

I am getting this screen
[image]

4. The problem is I a, not able to use arrows to select from the type of application nor I am able to select the default option by clicking Enter.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If your node version is v8.x, then you could see [bugs](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5905)

, the simple workaround is to change your node version to v6.11.0(LTS). 
Wish to help you.